# EF ef Database.SqlQuery internal rollback into executed stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I am using EF 6 Database.SqlQuery statement to execute stored procedure with implemented error and transaction handling, with opening and closing transactions (processing more than one record, if there is error with one record rollback only this, and commit anything else completed without errors).

```
List<T> _result = this.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sqlStatement, parameters).ToList();
```

EF uses its own transaction for execution of Database.SqlQuery, but when error occures, and I do rollback into stored procedure this rollback also applies on EF transacton. So i get the follwoing exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The current
>   transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that
>   write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

How can i prevent EF from using his own transaction in this case, or prevent procedure from closing EF's transaction?

Comment: Do not rollback in your stored procedure. Throw an exception and let the client handle it.

Comment: I don't want to change SP error handling because rollback it may be made only for one processed record inside. I want records without error to be commited.

Comment: Then you need to make EF not start a transaction. If there is an outer transaction all rows will be all or nothing.

Comment: Better yet, don't try to insert data that will fail constraint validation. You surely can make the system what you want but you are working a little against best practices here.

Comment: yes that is my question, if there is some way to prevent EF from openining its own transaction for SqlQuery statement. Because I don't have my own outer transaction. When separate transactions into stored procedure are OK, meaning there was no Rollback but Commit everithing is working. Commit does not close both transactions, but rollback does. Rollback into procedure closes my transaction, but also EFs transaction.

Comment: This stored proceudre is little bit complicated. It executes configured queries (mostly insert queries into tables, using Xpath to extract data from xml). It executes more than one Insert/Update query for n records, and the idea is to commit/rollback every one of them separately depending of execution status.

Comment: You might try calling Database.SqlQuery.UseTransaction(null) before SqlQuery.

Comment: It starts out null, not using a transaction. The problem is that it creates one automatically, and -- unlike the ExecuteSqlCommand -- provides NO option to NOT start a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out in this case there wasn't additonal transaction added by .SqlQuery command, but the error was produced by executed procedure into the inital executed stored procedure (yeh little bit complicated but it is really required). However I had this problem with external EntityFramework transaction with .ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand but I resolved this using TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction behaviour.

For Example:

```
        using (INotificationDataContext context = DataContextFactory.Create<INotificationDataContext>())
        {
            result = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, sql, parameters);
        }
```